# Openpyxl Chart anchor: how to use automated anchor not fixed one?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using this code right now,
which adds a chart into a fix anchor as:

```
ws.add_chart(chart, "B9")
```

chart fixed to add at cell B9
However, I'd like to add chart automatically after the max row + 2
because I have multi files with different data rows.
How can I do this?

I couldn't figure it out!

Comment: Should be able to just do **ws.add_chart(chart, f'B{ws.max_row+2}')**

Comment: Ooh, That's right.  I was putting it as ws.add_chart(chart, ws.max_row+2) .. thanks